# composer.json requires illuminate/support ^5.2

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, laravel-6, pusher

I try to install:

> composer require laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications

package to my laravel project. But i Keep receive this error

> > Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires illuminate/support ^5.2, found illuminate/support[v5.2.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

and here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "hekmatinasser/verta": "^1.10",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "morilog/jalali": "3.*",
        "shetabit/payment": "^4.0",
        "tzsk/sms": "^4.0",
        "illuminate/support" : "^5.2",
        "econea/nusoap": "v0.9.5.*",
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "dev-master"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in laravel. Hope anyone provide the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try deleting vendor and composer.lock and run `composer install` again

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour What about my other packages? They are all removed, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `illuminate/support` from your `composer.json` file. You are trying to use `laravel/framework ^7.0` which would provide you with `illuminate/support` for `^7.0` as its part of the framework.